# Ctrl+Right click is not extruding vertex to mouse but rather on top of the selected vertex

Tags: vertices

Vertex select is on and it's properly making new vertices but it's just making them on top of the existing one rather than to my mouse, any idea why this is? It works in other projects, and I've tried load factory settings and then open without loading UI and still no go.
[image]

Edit: If I add a new cube in the project I can extrude it just fine, it's just the original object that doesn't extrude properly. I can still grab the vertex and move it that way though.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, my scale in the Z direction was set to 0. While I was only working in the x/y dimensions, having 0 scale broke the mouse from working, even when the camera was perfectly set and orthogonal.

To fix: Go to object mode, press 'n' to open the Transform options on the right-hand, make sure Scale isn't set to 0. If you set dimensions to 0 it can set the scale to 0 as well.